# Unable to format timestamp sensor in home assistant / hass.io using strptime function

Tags: home-assistant

I am trying to display a sensor state value, which is of type 'timestamp' formatted as %H:%M but not able to get the strptime function to work the way I expect it.

e.g. in the Dev Tools when i add the below to the 'TEMPLATE' section

```
sunrise {{ strptime(state_attr("sun.sun", "next_rising"), "%H:%M") }}
```

it still displays the output as:

```
sunrise 2020-01-20T19:05:26+00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Home Assistant [Templating documentation](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/configuration/templating/#time):

- `strptime(string, format)` will **parse** a string to a datetime based on a format.

So that's not exactly what you need.

You may want to apply `timestamp_custom(format_string, local_boolean)` **filter** to convert a timestamp to a **custom format**, e.g:

`{{ as_timestamp(state_attr("sun.sun", "next_rising")) | timestamp_custom('%H:%M') }}`